# using barplot in ggplot without collapsing by groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I would like to use ggplot to create a barchart, but not aggregate the observations by (categorical) x. For example, here is what I want using the R base plot system:

```
library(ggplot2) 
data <- data.frame(lab = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "a"),
                   val = c(2, 5, 6, 3, 1))

barplot(data$val, names.arg = data$lab)
```

and here is what I want:
[image]

However, if I use ggplot, this is what I get:

```
ggplot(data, aes(lab, val)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

What is the right way of using ggplot to get the plot I want? Thanks!

Comment: How are two bars with the same label meaningful in any way? Feels like something is missing in your question or representation.

Comment: Hi @Molx, this is a good point. I only extracted the part relevant to my questions. The full story is that these a, b, b, a, a, c's could be case counts for users a, b, and c. And there is other case count level information that I plan to color code to visualize. Does that sound a little more reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new variable along the `lab` value as the `x` and then relabel them.

```
ggplot(data, aes(as.character(seq_along(lab)), val)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete("lab", labels = c("1" = "a", "2" = "b", "3" = "b", "4" = "c", "5" = "a"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Psidom! This trick solves my problem. And just a little revision for parsimonious code a little: we could use `scale_x_discrete("lab", labels = data$lab)` to save some space.